# Display time, network and battery status while in kiosk mode

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I have an application that needs to run in Kiosk-Mode (`Activity.startLockTask`) when the device is given to some users (only administrators can unlock the kiosk mode with a password). Unfortunately in this mode, the status bar is hidden. However having the time, network status (to know if some remote operations can complete) and battery status is important for the user.

Is there a way to show the status bar (or a custom one with only the needed information) while in Kiosk-Mode? Do I need to draw the time, network and battery indicator myself?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Any standard solutiion for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tested, but when being in kiosk mode (Android 5 Screen pinning?) you can try to enable the status bar back via WindowManager API or `setSystemUiVisibility()`, read here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

**ADDED**: status bar dimming seems to be a better fit for your purpose, as it probably disables the status bar but remains it visible: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html

Comment: I tried `setSystemUiVisibility` without success. I need to prevent also the user to exit the app so I use the KioskMode (that the user can easily exits but that is a first blocker) plus some hacks that watches the current application (some ideas taken from here: http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/)

Comment: it would be right to add the link to your description. The article describes kiosk mode for Android 4 devices, in Android 5 there are some system support for that mode, just FYI: https://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-3-android-lollipop. In your article I do not see where the full screen mode is set, I think that you could handle status bar settings there.

Comment: Indeed the link is quite old and not relevant for Android 5+, sorry. I use part of it (to restart the app after reboot). As updated in the description I'm using `Activity.startLockTask` (but I'm not a device owner app). Without going into immersive mode before, simply calling this method hides the status bar with no way (that I'm aware of) to bring it back except by calling stopLockTask...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable the status bar on the devices on and before Android 8 in Android Lock task mode. Android 9 and above, this feature is available via LOCK_TASK_FEATURES and you can enable the status bar button on the same.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_HOME

If your devices are below android 9, then you can build your own custom status bar within your own Kiosk mode app. In this you can use the wifi manager or AlarmManager etc to show in your status bar what you need.